# What happens if no objects are selected to be displayed in the softphone layout?

Tags: cti

We have no objects selected in 'display these salesforce objects' setting in the softphone layout.

In our CTI adapter settings we have Cases selected as an object to search on.

We notice the behavior is that Salesforce is still searching Cases upon an inbound call, and not respecting the Salesforce softphone layout setting as the master search setting.

However, if I add another object such as Account in the Salesforce softphone layout, but continue to have Case enabled in the CTI adapter settings, Salesforce will not search for Cases.

It is odd I have to add another object to the softphone layout settings in Salesforce for it to respect not to search Cases. Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Thankfully, there doesn't seem to be a risk of Accounts being searched because we have Account search disabled from the CTI adapter side (even though it is enabled in the Salesforce softphone layout).

Background: We only want to log calls against Cases (in the whatID field) in the softphone. We conduct our own search, and therefore want to turn off the search functionality. However, we still need the "Case search" functionality turned on in the CTI settings so that we can relate the call to the Case in the Related To in the softphone, based on the current Case in focus.